# Is there an aggregate using left or right join statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE tablea ( 
    id  char(25) NULL,
    qid int(11) NULL 
    ) 
GO
INSERT INTO tablea(id, qid) 
    VALUES('A', 3),('B', 3),('C', 3),('D', 3)
GO

CREATE TABLE tableb ( 
    pk  int(11) NOT NULL,
    qid varchar(25) NULL,
    cnt varchar(25) NULL 
    )
GO

INSERT INTO tableb(pk, qid, cnt) 
    VALUES(0, '3', 'A'),(1, '3', 'D'),(2, '3', 'A'),(3, '3', 'C'),(4, '3', 'A'),(5, '3', 'D'),(6, '3', 'A'),(7, '3', 'A'),
GO
```

By counting TableB, Total Cnt as per TableA's ID is: A=5, B=0, C=1, D=2. When select count(Cnt) group by ID, the result does not include B, i.e. result: A=5,C=1,D=2.

How can I include B=0 using mySQL.

Comment: post the select sql statement you are trying to execute and I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is;

```
SELECT id, COUNT(cnt) FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON id=cnt GROUP BY id;
```

Which will count in TableB the occurrences of all ID's in TableA even if they don't exist in TableB.

(side note, your naming is a bit hard to figure out)

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time spent.